# strings in C, (i'm newbie in C)

Tags: c, string

I'm newbie in C language, so probably this is a stupid qeustions, but i don't know what to do. this is my trouble:

why this code doesn't print nothing?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


void function(char* valor);

main()
{
char* valor;
int s;

    valor=(char*)malloc(101*sizeof(char));
    function(valor);
    printf("%s\n",valor);

return 0;
}

void function(char* valor)
{

    valor="ciao";

}
```

and this print the string i want? ("ciao")

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

main()
{
char* valor;

    valor=(char*)malloc(101*sizeof(char));
    valor="ciao";
    printf("%s\n",valor);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: http://c-faq.com/ptrs/passptrinit.html

Comment: FYI: You are allocating memory and assigning a pointer to it.  Then you are re-assigning the pointer to a static string which is abandoning the memory you allocated.   Memory Leak!

Answer (score 1):

The variable `valor` inside the function and the variable `valor` in main are different variables.

When you change the value of `valor` inside the function, nothing happens to `valor` in main.

Answer (score 1):

Your `function()` sets its internal copy of the 'valor' pointer to point to a string constant. The original copy in the stack of `main()` remains intact, i.e. garbage (or possibly zero).